# AppExchange package versions

Tags: managed-package, appexchange

Maybe someone knows if it is possible to have multiple current versions on the AppExchange. The fact is that different customers need different package modifications (some different components and logic). Maybe someone has dealt with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary for customers to use the version listed on the AppExchange; the customer simply needs the package version ID (the value for the p0 parameter in the package install URL) and, if needed, the install key. They can then simply use the package version ID in a package install URL against their org to get that version installed.

Note, however, that what you are talking about is **not** an appropriate product development approach. Products are intended to provide the functionality in a way that many customers can use it. If some customer(s) need different behaviour you should either:

- Leave that behaviour outside the package, added as a local "customization" using standard Salesforce functionality (e.g. a custom record triggered flow).
- Provide a setting (custom permission, custom setting, custom metadata type etc.) to allow the behaviour to be selected from a set of options.
- Provide an API that allows customization of that behaviour (this API enabling a subscriber to include apex or a flow that implements the behaviour they want).

If the behaviour needed by a customer is not something applicable to any others then you should go the "local" or "API" route - a product must not include customer-specific logic.

Managing different "version branches" for different customers is simply not a scalable solution and will cause you real headaches if you try; you will be continually having to merge bug fixes and new features into every customer-specific branch, creating new versions for those customers (only possible with 2GP, but then you have to ensure you use the correct ancestry). It's a path to confusion and disaster.

Comment: But I have several types of customers... Do you think internal settings (based on customer types) in the middle of the package would be a better solution?

Comment: I work for an ISV with many, many customers with varying needs. The product doesn't include any customer-specific functionality, instead providing "standard functionality" (read: functionality that would be used by multiple customers) with various settings to allow the behaviour to be varied. When customers want to do something the package doesn't do, this is done in their org directly, either using standard Salesforce stuff or (when the behaviour needs to partially replace or be added to packaged behaviour) using an API we provide. APIs are typically global Apex classes or interfaces.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: One more question: is it possible to choose version when install package from AppEx?

Comment: No - in that scenario you get the one that is currently selected in the App Exchange listing.

Comment: The fact you are still asking such makes me think you are still going the "route of pain", with different versions for different customers. Honestly, if you are, this is a very bad idea.

Comment: No, I wanted to clarify these points for myself.
Fine. I realized that only one general version for all. thanks for the quick replies. Good luck!

Comment: OK, good. I hope this saves you from a lot of difficulties in servicing your customers.

Comment: Maybe you know who pays for the security review initiated by Salesforce (once a year)?

Comment: The partner pays, unless the app is free in which case you can request a voucher from Salesforce that covers the cost. Salesforce initiate security reviews when they see fit; this can be between 6 months to over 2 years AFAIK.